# NSIS - Validating radio button selection

Tags: nsis

I have a really simple NSIS script that allows the user to select which component they would like to install, but I need a way of saying "Please select a component" if they haven't selected anything.

Here's the script:

```
# Based on the one-section example
# http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/one-section.nsi

!include "sections.nsh"

Name "Humira & You"
OutFile "Humira & You - September 2012.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel user

Page components
Page instfiles

Section /o "Rheumatoid Arthritis" P1
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\Setup.msi" "setupfiles\Humira and you - Rheumatoid Arthritis.msi"
SectionEnd

Section /o "Psoriatic Arthritis" P2
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\Setup.msi" "setupfiles\Humira and you - Psoriatic Arthritis.msi"
SectionEnd

Section /o "Ankylosing Spondylitis" P3
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\Setup.msi" "setupfiles\Humira and you - Ankylosing Spondylitis.msi"
SectionEnd

Section /o "Axial Spondyloarthritis" P4
    File "/oname=$pluginsdir\Setup.msi" "setupfiles\Humira and you - Axial Spondyloarthritis.msi"
SectionEnd

Section ; Hidden section that runs the show
    DetailPrint "Installing selected application..."
    SetDetailsPrint none
    ExecWait '"msiexec" /i "$pluginsdir\Setup.msi"'
    SetDetailsPrint lastused
SectionEnd

Function .onInit
    Initpluginsdir ; Make sure $pluginsdir exists
    StrCpy $1 ${P2} ;The default
FunctionEnd

Function .onSelChange
!insertmacro StartRadioButtons $1
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${P1}
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${P2}
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${P3}
    !insertmacro RadioButton ${P4}
!insertmacro EndRadioButtons
FunctionEnd
```

I had a look around and came across this example, http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Useful_InstallOptions_and_MUI_macros#Macro:_CHECKBOXCHECKER, but it seems overly complex for what I want. Is there no way to say in NSIS:

```
if ($1.selectedIndex > -1) {
   // continue
} else {
   MessageBox.Show("Please select");
}
```

Thanks,
Greg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *callback function* when leaving the components page to check if one is selected.

Here is a piece of code that I use in a setup. I use a little macro to summarize in a variable the selected components. If there is none, the variable is null. I use the `PageEx` block to associate callback functions to the component page (as the leave callback is the third one, I use a dummy function for the first two others)

Replace

```
Page components
```

by

```
PageEx components
    PageCallbacks DummyFunc DummyFunc componentsLeave
PageExEnd
```

keep your `.onSelChange` call back to handle exclusive selection, then add this to the end of your script :

```
!define SECTIONCOUNT 3 ; total -1
;SaveSections adds one bit to the given variable for each selected component
!macro SaveSections VAR
    StrCpy ${VAR} 0
    ${ForEach} $R0 ${SECTIONCOUNT} 0 - 1
        IntOp ${VAR} ${VAR} << 1
        ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} $R0
            ;${DEBUG} "Section $R0 checked"
            IntOp ${VAR} ${VAR} + 1
        ${EndIf}
    ${Next}
!macroend

Function DummyFunc
FunctionEnd

Function componentsLeave
    !insertmacro SaveSections $2
    ${if} $2 = 0
        MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Select something !" /sd IDOK
        Abort
    ${endif}
FunctionEnd
```